# Linux network manager getting two ip addresses instead of one

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, dhcp, networkmanager

I have a problem that when I connect to network using NetworkManager in Linux (doesn't happen when using wpa_supplicant but I don't like it) it gets two IPv4 addresses that show up as for example 192.168.43.28 and 192.168.43.27 / 24 in NetworkManager connection info.

In effect, it shows up as two devices in the Android mobile router menu. I just don't like to see more connections than there really exist.

How can I make it get only one IP address using DHCP in NetworkManager?

Here is my `ip a` output when I'm connected to wifi. You can see two addresses `192.168.1.157/24` and `192.168.1.158/24`. Second one says `secondary`.

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp7s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:5a:6e:6f:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 56:61:24:a9:fc:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr 00:23:4e:d9:28:11
    inet 192.168.1.157/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 42877sec preferred_lft 42877sec
    inet 192.168.1.158/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global secondary dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 42888sec preferred_lft 37488sec
```

I'm using Void Linux x86_64 glibc.

Comment: Can you please edit your post and add the output of `ip a`?

Comment: Do you somehow have two DHCP clients running? (Are there any 'dhcpcd' or 'dhclient' processes?)

Comment: There is one `dhcpcd: [master] [ip4] [ip6]` started by `runsv dhcpcd`

Comment: It turns out there was runit dhcpcd service getting extra IP address. Removing it by `sudo rm /var/service/dhcpcd` and rebooting the system fixed the issue. Thanks @user1686 for help!

Comment: Same here on Void Linux x86_64. Networkmanager and dhcpcd have been active.